# ComboBox filtering in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding, combobox, checkbox

I have a question regarding ComboBox binding.

I have a comboBox, filled with some values, and I want to filter this comboBox, only to show values that satisfy value of checkBox.

For example: I have a checkBox named Male. And when I checked it, I want to display in comboBox only objects which Gender is Male.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your ComboBox to a collection, say an observable collection and two way binding of the check box to a bool.
When you click on check box your bool property will be notified. Based on that filter your collection. The combo box will now have filtered items.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PagedCollectionView.  Pass your collection that your ComboBox currently binds to to the PageCollectionView, then bind to that.  The PagedCollectionView has a Filter property that takes a Predicate to filter the items in your collection.

There are some issues with the filter that cause it to not to update when properties used within the filter are updated.  Also, it does not update when the items are changed.  To force it to update, you can set it to null then back to it's original value.  You might be able to something with the Refresh method, but I have not tested that.